# Check if Input is empty doesnt work Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hey guys i just started playing around with android studio and wanted to make an app that calculates the faculty of an input value. It works if i give it an Input Value but if not it crashes, so i tried to check if the input is empty but that didn´t solve the error. Here´s the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    val Output = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Output)
    val Input = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Input)

    Button.setOnClickListener {


        val num = Input.text.toString().toInt()
        if(num.toString().isNotBlank()) {




            var hilf = 1

            for (i in 1..num.toString().toInt()) {
                hilf *= i

            }
            Output.text = hilf.toString()
        }



    }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea how i could fix the problem?

Comment: can you copy the error?

Comment: You perform the `isNotBlank` check after you call `toInt`, which is too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you check if the `EditText` is empty and then try to convert to `Int`:

```
if(!Input.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
    val num = Input.text.toString().toInt()
    var hilf = 1

    for (i in 1..num) {
        hilf *= i
    }
    Output.text = hilf.toString()
}
```

Also you don't need

```
num.toString().toInt()
```

you can just use

```
1..num
```

because `num`'s type is `Int`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. So my app crashed at the val num = Input.text.toString().toInt() right?

Comment: Your app would crash at `Input.text.toString().toInt()` when Input was empty or contained other characters than numeric.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the following:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    val Output = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Output)
    val Input = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Input)

    Button.setOnClickListener {
        val num = Input.text.toString().toInt()
        if(!Input.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            var hilf = 1
            for (i in 1..num.toString().toInt()) {
                hilf *= i
            }
            Output.text = hilf.toString()
        }
    }
}
```